# My app craches when I open fragment from notification

Tags: android, firebase

I am developing Android polling app. Admin sends notification to all the users and they open the notification that gets them to polling fragment. For some reason when admin sends the notification, only the device from which it has been sent can access the polling fragment and other users app crashes. This is stack trace I get

```
022-07-07 15:02:40.227 13564-13564/praksa.atos.evotingsystem E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: praksa.atos.evotingsystem, PID: 13564
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{praksa.atos.evotingsystem/praksa.atos.evotingsystem.view.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #10 in praksa.atos.evotingsystem:layout/activity_main: Binary XML file line #10 in praksa.atos.evotingsystem:layout/activity_main: Error inflating class androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3846)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:4022)
    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2336)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:246)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8653)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:602)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1130)
 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #10 in praksa.atos.evotingsystem:layout/activity_main: Binary XML file line #10 in praksa.atos.evotingsystem:layout/activity_main: Error inflating class androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #10 in praksa.atos.evotingsystem:layout/activity_main: Error inflating class androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Wrong argument type for 'surveyId' in argument bundle. string expected.
    at androidx.navigation.NavDestination.addInDefaultArgs(NavDestination.kt:502)
    at androidx.navigation.NavController.navigate(NavController.kt:1689)
    at androidx.navigation.NavController.handleDeepLink(NavController.kt:1275)
    at androidx.navigation.NavController.onGraphCreated(NavController.kt:1154)
    at androidx.navigation.NavController.setGraph(NavController.kt:1086)
    at androidx.navigation.NavController.setGraph(NavController.kt:1039)
    at androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment.onCreate(NavHostFragment.kt:155)
    at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performCreate(Fragment.java:2981)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.create(FragmentStateManager.java:474)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStateManager.java:257)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:1840)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:1764)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.execSingleAction(FragmentManager.java:1670)
    at androidx.fragment.app.BackStackRecord.commitNowAllowingStateLoss(BackStackRecord.java:323)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView.<init>(FragmentContainerView.kt:158)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentLayoutInflaterFactory.onCreateView(FragmentLayoutInflaterFactory.java:53)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentController.onCreateView(FragmentController.java:135)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.dispatchFragmentsOnCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:295)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:274)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.tryCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:1067)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:995)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:959)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1121)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1082)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:680)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:532)
```

2022-07-07 15:02:40.228 13564-13564/praksa.atos.evotingsystem E/AndroidRuntime:     at praksa.atos.evotingsystem.databinding.ActivityMainBinding.inflate(ActivityMainBinding.java:45)
at praksa.atos.evotingsystem.databinding.ActivityMainBinding.inflate(ActivityMainBinding.java:39)
at praksa.atos.evotingsystem.view.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:21)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8207)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8191)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1309)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3819)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:4022)
at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85)
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2336)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:246)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8653)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:602)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1130)

And this is my messaging service

```
public class FirebaseMessagingService extends com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService {

NotificationManager mNotificationManager;


@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);


    Uri notification = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
    Ringtone r = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(getApplicationContext(), notification);
    r.play();
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.P) {
        r.setLooping(false);
    }

    Vibrator v = (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
    long[] pattern = {100, 300, 300, 300};
    v.vibrate(pattern, -1);


    int resourceImage = getResources().getIdentifier(remoteMessage.getNotification().getIcon(), "drawable", getPackageName());



    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, "CHANNEL_ID");
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.atos);
    } else {;
        builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.atos);
    }
    Intent resultIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);

    TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(this);
    stackBuilder.addNextIntentWithParentStack(resultIntent);

    NavDeepLinkBuilder navDeepLinkBuilder = new NavDeepLinkBuilder(this);

    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putString("surveyId", SurveySingleton.getInstance().getSurveyId());
    args.putString("email", SurveySingleton.getInstance().getEmail());
    args.putInt("storyNumber", SurveySingleton.getInstance().getStoryNumber());

    PendingIntent pendingIntent = navDeepLinkBuilder.setComponentName(MainActivity.class).setGraph(R.navigation.nav_graph).setArguments(args)
                    .setDestination(R.id.surveyFragment).createPendingIntent();

    builder.setContentText(remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
    builder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
    builder.setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody()));
    builder.setAutoCancel(true);
    builder.setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_MAX);

    mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
    {
        String channelId = "Your_channel_id";
        NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(
                channelId,
                "Channel human readable title",
                NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);
        mNotificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
        builder.setChannelId(channelId);
    }

    mNotificationManager.notify(100, builder.build());
}
```

}

Comment: Seems like you're getting a pretty clear error in the log: "Wrong argument type for 'surveyId' in argument bundle. string expected."

Comment: Yeah but when I start the poll fragment from the device the notification has been sent it works fine, but on other devices the app crashes.

Comment: Well how are you reading the value? I can see you're using putString to write, but are you using getString to read it?

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).